# Int32Converter cannot convert from 'MyNamespace.MyEnum' when data-binding ComboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

*For skimmers.* The question is near the bottom just after the bold text.

I am data-binding a `ComboBox` to an enumeration type using an `ObjectDataProvider`. The `ObjectDataProvider` is very simple.

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FaultAreaValues" 
                    ObjectType="{x:Type FaultTrackCoreDBValues:FaultAreas}"
                    MethodName="GetValues">

    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="FaultTrackCoreDBValues:FaultAreas" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>

</ObjectDataProvider>
```

I data-bind the `ComboBox` via `ItemsSource`, which is also simple.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FaultAreaValues}}"
```

All of this works fine. The `ComboBox` is populated with the proper values from the enumeration. I am also using the MVVM Pattern, so the view's `DataContext` is set to an instance of its associated `ViewModel`, which looks (trimmed down) like this.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IFault _Fault;

    public IFault Fault {
        get {
            return _Fault;
        }
        set {
            _Fault = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Fault");
        }
    }
}
```

And the Model:

```
public interface IFault
{
    FaultAreas Area { get; set; }
}

public partial class Fault : IFault, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FaultAreas IFault.Area {
        get {
            return (FaultAreas)Area;
        }
        set {
            Area = (Int32)value;
        }
    }
}
```

**It is important to note that `Fault` is a partial class that is actually an `Entity` in an Entity Data Model.** Because Entity does not support enumerations prior to .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 4.5, I use an explicit interface to add that support, as well as completely decouple everything from knowing anything about the Entity objects.

Here is the actual `SelectedItem` binding:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Fault.Area}"
```

The problem is that the selection of the ComboBox is never initially set, and changing the selection causes the adorner to show, and causes the following exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'Behavior' from type
>   'FaultAreas' to type 'System.Int32' for 'en-US' culture with default
>   conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter
>   cannot convert from FaultTrack.Core.DBValues.FaultAreas.    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
>   value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type
>   destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean isForward)'

I'm not sure what causes this. I can solve the error by binding to a `FaultAreas` property directly on the ViewModel, but that's not what I want to do. I want to bind to the instance of the model `IFault`, and understand why this error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I change you code a little bit.

```
public partial class Fault : IFault, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private FaultAreas _area;
    public FaultAreas Area 
    {
        get { return (FaultAreas)_area; }
        set 
        {
            _area= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Area");
        }
   }
 }
```

I can see initial value and binding the selecteditem works too. I just change the interface implementation and call OnPropertyChanged("Area"); .

EDIT: It also works with explicit interface implementation

```
public partial class Fault : IFault, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int Area;

    public Fault()
    {
        Area = 0;//default?
    }

    FaultAreas IFault.Area
    {
        get{ return (FaultAreas)Area; }
        set
        {
            Area = (int)value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Area");
        }
    }
 }
```

the binding looks like the following then:

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Fault.(local:IFault.Area)}"
```

Comment: Last night I was able to get the binding to propagate changes using the same syntax `Fault.(FaultTrack.Data.IFault.Area)`, however the initial selection still does not work (even with `OnPropertyChanged("Area")`). The code you have differs from what I have in one very important aspect, `Area = (Int32)value`. `Area` is an `Int32` property on the Entity model `Fault` so it must be cast. The only thing now is the initial selection is not set.

Comment: I'll explain why this helped solve the issue, its most certainly not the entire root cause, but a helpful portion.

Comment: edit my code for your int cast need. still works for me and a initial selection is made. debug your app with a breakpoint in your IFault.Area getter to see the value for your initial selection. maybe the is no default set and so no initail selection made.